# Heartbeat is not running on centos?

Tags: linux, centos, heartbeat

i'm install on centos

```
CRITICAL: Resource IPaddr::192.168.137.20/24/eth0 is active, and should not be!
```

fix: remove alias `/etc/network/interface` but i'm not find link `/etc/network/interface` on centos ?

Comment: Try `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network interfaces in CentOS are configured in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`, in files named after the interface, e.g. `ifcfg-eth0`. See [the doc](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Network_Interfaces.html).